# Hardware Simulation

Tags: hardware, emulation

I'm working on a software project intended for recuperating old specific hardware, mostly for non-for-profit organizations and poor schools.

I need a way to simulate old hardware so I can test the application before shipping it out.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to simulate the hardware - the hardware is a black box which your software talks to, and you want to replace than black box with other software, or emulate the hardware - your software runs on your machine which acts like the emulated hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the question is asking for. I think you are asking for a way to emulate certain HW?

If that is the case, I've used [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Index.html) in the past, and it has worked great. QEMU is an open source machine emulator and virtualizer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine)? Prepare the images reflecting (more or less) the state of the target machines (speed, hardware, etc). And use them for testing the deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Emulator Zone](http://www.emulator-zone.com/), and emulator is a good google search term you might not have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Well. If the old hardware is communicating via RS232, then write a class that wraps the RS232 commands and make the class inject the messages the old hardwares would respond. In your program,  work against that class instead of real rs232-port and just change instance to real rs232 before shipping.

I have done this succesfully in a project and it worked out really good and its not that complicated that you can think.